# Cassandra DSE Service on Linux with non-default Installation Location

Tags: linux, service, installation, cassandra

How can I install Cassandra DataStax Enterprise on RHEL6 in a non-default location and still have it run as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Try using --installroot with yum:

> --installroot=root
>       Specifies an alternative installroot, relative to which all packages will be installed.